# ASP Classic SQL Query Error Message - Invalid number

Tags: sql, asp-classic, oracle12c

I got a query using SQL inside ASP Classic, and the syntax that I got is shown below:

```
    mQry = "SELECT name FROM finals WHERE invoice_num = " &request.querystring("num") & " AND name LIKE '&" & request.querystring("nam") & "%'"
    response.write("Operating Unit")
    for each x in TestRally.fields
    response.write(": ")
    response.write(x.value)  '-- got error in this area...
    response.write("<br>")
    next
    response.write("<br>")
    TestRally.MoveNext
```

Based on the above mentioned syntax, what would be the best possible remedy for this..???

The error message I got so far is this:

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Oracle error '80040e07' ORA-01722:
>   invalid number

Comment: Print out `mQry`.  In my experience, looking at the query string after variable substitutions makes the fix obvious about 95% of the time.

Comment: I would think `&request.querystring("num")` is not a number.

Comment: Or maybe my SQL query is wrong... so that I got that error message

Comment: What DBMS are you using? MS Access? Microsoft SQL Server? MySQL?

Comment: Where do you populate `TestRally` ?

Comment: DBMS that I am using is "Oracle 12c"

Comment: How are you using your 12c database? Are you using OLE-DB, ODBC (with `ADODB`) or something provided by Oracle?

Comment: Set TestRally = CreateObject("Adodb.recordset")
mQry="SELECT DISTINCT name FROM best WHERE invoice_num =" & request.querystring("num") & " AND name LIKE '%" & request.querystring("nam") & "%' "
   Set TestRally = oraConn.Execute(mQry)

response.write("Operating Unit")
 for each x in TestRally.fields
  response.write(": ")
  response.write(x.value)     '-- got error in this area..???
  response.write("<br>")
 next
 Response.Write("<br>")
 TestRally.MoveNext

TestRally.close
oraConn.close
Response.Write("<br>")

Comment: Any remedy you can give me for this one..?

Comment: no one can answer this...

Comment: Where is `mQry` used...

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP Classic SQL Query with two parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18505155/asp-classic-sql-query-with-two-parameters)

Comment: Is this related to your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18490131/25163)?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is wide-open to SQL injection attacks and that is partly the cause of your problem: you're not verifying (let alone sanitizing) your input that you use to formulate queries.

See this QA before continuing: [What is SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection)

We can't tell you how to properly solve it without knowing what DBMS you're using, but a quick workaround is this:

```
Dim invoiceNum
invoiceNum = CInt( Request.QueryString("num") )
Dim name
name = Request.QueryString("nam")
name = Replace( name, "'", "''" )

Dim sql
sql = "SELECT name FROM finals WHERE invoice_num = " & invoiceNum & " AND name LIKE '&" & name & "%'"
```

Comment: I am currently using Oracle 12c for the DBMS

Comment: @RallyCautiverio how is it not functioning?

Answer (score 0):

```
invoiceNum = CInt( Request.QueryString("num") )
```

is probably causing the overflow.

The invoice number you are passing is too big for an integer. Save the invoice number as string.

Using Dai's code, try this:

```
Dim invoiceNum
invoiceNum = Request.QueryString("num")
invoiceNum = Replace( invoiceNum, "'", "''")

Dim name
name = Request.QueryString("nam")
name = Replace( name, "'", "''" )

sql = "EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT name FROM finals WHERE invoice_num = @invoice_num AND name LIKE ''&'' + @name + ''%'''"
sql = sql & ",N'@invoice_num varchar(20),@name varchar(255)',@invoice_num = '" & invoiceNum & "',@name = '" & name & "'"
```

Comment: You advice a wrong way to build a query concatenating parameter values to the command string instead of using parameters. Doing that is wrong and puts the security of your database in risk.

Answer (score 0):

Enable sql tracing or better 10046 tracing before executing the above statement and you will see which value is passed in for the invoice_num. This will create a trace file that details all the statements and how they are executed.

In addition post how the table has been defined.

Answer (score 0):

"SELECT name FROM finals WHERE invoice_num='" & request.querystring("num") &  "' AND name = '" & request.querystring("nam") & "'"

This is the right SQL syntax for the query inside the ASP Classic instead of the above-mentioned SQL query that I have in my question.